# Maven repository: connection timeout

Tags: maven

It is became unable to download any artifact from http://repo.aduno-software.com repository  (connection timed out). Issues lasts for couple weeks.

Is there any substitution for that repo and may be anybody knows whom to complain about server's out of service condition ?

I've tried out lots of different maven repositories but they  even all together can not cover all my project's dependencies while the mentioned one does.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be getting a timeout error.  That domain name [does not exist](http://whois.domaintools.com/aduno-software.com).  Also, please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: Thanks for the advice on tags. 'll keep it in mind! There was a misprinting in domain name - the right one is: http://repo.aduna-software.org. But anyway, it makes no difference as connections is timed out. Is there any real substitution ?

Answer (score 1):

Note this this work around is kind of hacky and it might only work if the data is also available from other repos. 
Here is what I came up with (Maven docs explains all of these settings):

  1. Find settings xml under your Maven directory.
  On Windows, it in is there under conf\settings.xml

  2. Add mirrors to the settings file:

```
  <mirrors>
<!-- mirror
 | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
 | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
 | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
 |
<mirror>
  <id>mirrorId</id>
  <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
  <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
  <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
</mirror>
 -->
<mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.org</id>
  <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
<mirror>
 <id>ibiblio.net</id>
  <url>http://www.ibiblio.net/pub/packages/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>http://repo.aduna-software.org/maven2/releases/</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
<mirror>
  <id>uk.maven.org</id>
  <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

  3. To make sure that connection to repo.aduna-software.org times out fast, add
  ```
  127.0.0.1 repo.aduna-software.org
  ```
  to your host files

Order of mirror entries matter - maven tries the first mirror first, so you might need to tweak it.